# An invalid Form

Tags: php, html, pdo

When I try to connect with the true credentials I got some error with "Username and Password are not found"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login Page PHP Script</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    label
    {
        font-weight:bold;
        width:100px;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    .box
    {
        border:1px solid #006D9C;
        margin-left:10px;
        width:60%;
    }
    .submit{
        border:1px solid #006D9C;
        background-color:#006D9C;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        float:right;
        padding:2px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <div align="center">
        <div class="tLink"><strong>Login Detail:</strong></div><br />
        <div style="width:300px; border: solid 1px #006D9C; " align="left">
            <?php
                if(isset($errMsg)){
                    echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">'.$errMsg.'</div>';
                }
            ?>
            <div style="background-color:#006D9C; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>
            <div style="margin:30px">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <label>Username  :</label><input type="text" name="username" class="box"/><br /><br />
                    <label>Password  :</label><input type="password" name="password" class="box" /><br/><br />
                    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" class='submit'/><br />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();

//DB configuration Constants
define('_HOST_NAME_', '127.0.0.1');
define('_USER_NAME_', 'root');
define('_DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('_DATABASE_NAME_', 'ads_database');

//PDO Database Connection
try {
    $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='._HOST_NAME_.';dbname='._DATABASE_NAME_, _USER_NAME_, _DB_PASSWORD);
    $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $errMsg = '';
    //username and password sent from Form
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if($username == '')
        $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';

    if($password == '')
        $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';


    if($errMsg == ''){
        $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT nom_user, pass_user FROM  user WHERE nom_user = :username');
        $records->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['pass_user'])){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
            header('location:dashboard.php');
            exit;
        }else{
            $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your query failed and for possibly a few reasons. Although, my *Spidey sense* is telling me otherwise, being password column length being too short `if < 60 { problem }`. Spidey's also sensing someone biting on my comment. *Wait for it...*

Comment: I'm having trouble differentiating from; if it's a PDO connection question or the login itself. If it's PDO connection, then try changing `define('_HOST_NAME_', '127.0.0.1');` to `define('_HOST_NAME_', 'localhost');` - You want help, we want answers too from comments. So don't be shy to step in here. I'm not going to stand around any much more longer. and a magic answer will NOT appear. But then again; the sun's starting to go down somewhere, so it's just a matter of time I guess.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Help @Fred-ii- thank you for your comment, but the problem is not the password column length because is 255 ...Any other solution please?

Comment: @DrFlow You're welcome. Now, did you initially create/store a hash using `password_hash()`? and what is the column type? and try `fetchAll()` instead of `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: @DrFlow Scratch my comment about using `fetchAll()`. I tried that myself and it failed, so the problem may be in the way you created the password(s). I've tested your code and it worked fine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The column type is VARCHAR

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you give some details of what you mean about "the way you created the password(s)" please?

Comment: @DrFlow as in how the password was entered the db, we don't know that and if you did you `password_hash()` or a matching hard-code hash that was enterered in db. It's all in my answer below.

Comment: Look how I update the database in registration form  :

Comment: <?php
// Connexion à la base de données
try
{
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ads_database;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

if ( $_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2'] )
{
    echo "Les 2 mots de passe sont différents";
     
}

Comment: // Insertion du message à l'aide d'une requête préparée
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO user (nom_user, type_user, phone_user, ville_user, email_user, pass_user) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$req->execute(array($_POST['nom'], $_POST['type_user'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['post_ville_select'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']));

// Redirection du visiteur vers la page du minichat
header('Location: index.php');
?>

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** As you stated in comments, the length of the column is 255. Therefore it may very well be in the way you originally stored the password(s) and that method is unknown.

- **Consult my footnotes.**

<strike>I am next to convinced that your password column is too short in length, since your code checks out which is why I decided to post my answer, seeing you're not responding to comments.</strike>

If that is indeed the case, and that password column's length is less than 60 long, it needs to be altered to be that; 60 or even 255 as the manual states to be a good choice.

- This is something that is often overlooked.

You will need to first delete the present hashes, alter the column's length, create a new hash and query after.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

---

**Footnotes:**

You also would have needed to create/stored a hash. If you only stored plain text, then that is the problem here then.

Your PHP version also needs to support the `password_hash()` function if you did try and use that during the password/hash creation.

Otherwise, you will need to use the compatibility pack.

- https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat